# how to append value in select tag inside dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

im adding table row data using json response. here is my code

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {

    $.get('LoadserviceSplit', {
        "sectcode" : result[i]
    },
        function (jsonResponse) {
        if (jsonResponse != null) {
            var table2 = $("#table_assign");
            $.each(jsonResponse, function (key, value) {
                var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['serviceId']);
                rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['title']);
                rowNew.children().eq(2).html('<input type="text" id="date_set" name="date_set"/>');
                rowNew.children().eq(3).html('<input type="text" id="date_set1" name="date_set1"/>');
                rowNew.children().eq(4).html('<input type="text" id="date_set2" name="date_set2"/>');
                rowNew.children().eq(5).html('<select class="status1" id="status1">');

                rowNew.appendTo(table2);

            });
        }
    });

    var pass_unit_code = "001";
    $.get('LoadDivisionCodeServlet', { //call LoadDivisionCodeServlet controller
        unitCode : pass_unit_code //pass the value of "sample" to unitCode:
    }, function (jsonResponse) { //json response
        var select = $('#status1'); //select #status1 option
        select.find('option').remove(); //remoev all item in #divcode option
        $.each(jsonResponse, function (index, value) {
            $('<option>').val(value).text(value).appendTo(select); //response from JSON in array value{column:value,column:value,column:value}
        });
    });

}
```

it works fine except the select tag part. only the first row of table have value. the rest has no value. i want all drop-down list inside the table has same value.. can anyone help me about this.

Comment: This is pure Javascript with jQuery, why is the question tagged with `jsp` or `java-ee`?

Comment: sorry i'm a beginner sir. i will edit it right away

Comment: sorry can you explain it more? whare you want to same value and where i get it?

Comment: i want all <select class="status1" id="status1"> have value inside the table. sorry if i cant explain it clearly sir.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

`rowNew.children().eq(5).html('<select class="status1" id="status1">');`

You're creating new `select` elements in a `$.each` and assigning the same id, that is `status1` to all of them.

Then you're selecting the `select` element that has an `id` of `status1` like

`var select = $('#status1'); //select #status1 option`

Therefore, only the first `select` element will be selected.

EDIT:

Your question is not completely clear.

However, this is how you can add different Id for select inside each of your `<td>`

Replace this

`rowNew.children().eq(5).html('<select class="status1" id="status1">');`

With something like

`rowNew.children().eq(5).html('<select class="status1" id="status'+key+'">');`

So this will have different Ids.

Comment: thats my problem i have same "id" cos it add repeatedly according to the size of table. can you give me some idea how can i add all select tag with same value inside the table?

Comment: var select = $('#status1');  i got the idea but i dont know how to select each id with same id inside the table.

Comment: or key can be int which is increased inside each loop

Comment: i try to use the alert(key) i get 2 data in the database. the alert shows "0" twice. why it doesn't increase although it get 2 data in database. sorry for my noob question sir.